# Is it possible to create programing language same as Java but with cutom/better syntax?

Tags: java, syntax, programming-languages, customization

I am wondering about if it is possible to create the same programing language as Java is. Language with same libraries as in Java and other stuff but with modified syntax? I know, I want something that is hard. Probably what I want to modify JVM and compilation process somehow.

I thought about a lot of improvements that I would like to implement in Java.

There are some of the them that I think will be the easiest to do if possible:

1. Make `package` keyword optional. In other words, make the program automatically figured out the package based on files that is .java file placed in. For example:

```
//Package can, but do not need to be here!

import java.util.Arrays;
import some.awesome.thing.Lol;
//And others...

public class Main
{
//blabla
}
```

2. Better import management. The way to specify the Object name that will be used. This is big problem in java because you cant import 2 objects with same name. For example, there are over 30 objects called "Type" and I can import only one of them and others need to be write also with whole package name what is annoying.
   What I would like to do is:

```
//Package can, but do not need to be here!

//">>" means something like "as". Its not necesary to be exactly ">>" operator it was just an idea it can be something else...
//means import object X (with name that can be anything) as given object from package...
import FxColor >> javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import AwtColor >> java.awt.Color;
import MyAwesomeColor >> some.awesome.thing.enums.Color;
//And others...

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       System.out.println(FxColor.BLUE + " is nice!");
       System.out.println(AwtColor.BLUE + " is also good!");
       System.out.println(MyAwesomeColor.BLUE + " is the best!");
    }
}
```

3. Pre-import some things. This thing already exists in Java. I mean we do not need to import things from java.lang.* such as System or String. But what about to static pre-import certain things?
   For example:

```
//Package can, but do not need to be here!

//import static java.lang.System.*; invisibly for every object.

import FxColor >> javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import AwtColor >> java.awt.Color;
import MyAwesomeColor >> some.awesome.thing.enums.Color;
//And others...

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       out.println("Current time in nanos is " + nanoTime());

       out.println(FxColor.BLUE + " is nice!");
       out.println(AwtColor.BLUE + " is also good!");
       out.println(MyAwesomeColor.BLUE + " is the best!");
    }
}
```

4. `public class` as optional. Every `public class` will be optional to write. Program will automatically figure it out from file name. But if I want anything else then `public class`, I will be forced to write it manually For example: `public final class`, `protected class` or others.
   Code example:

```
//Package can, but do not need to be here!

//import static java.lang.System.*; invisibly for every object.

import FxColor >> javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import AwtColor >> java.awt.Color;
import MyAwesomeColor >> some.awesome.thing.enums.Color;
//public class X do not need to be there as far as it is public class...
//In this case, the class invisibly starts after the last import and has no end. I can type 1000 enters and I will be still in this class. 

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    out.println(FxColor.BLUE + " is nice!");
    out.println(AwtColor.BLUE + " is also good!");
    out.println(MyAwesomeColor.BLUE + " is the best!");
    out.println("Current time in nanos is " + nanoTime());
}
```

5. Connections between some datatypes. Now I think it will be better to explain directly on code:

```
//Package can, but do not need to be here!

//import static java.lang.System.*; invisibly for every object.

//Other imports...

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    a = "hi"; //Do not need to strictly specify variable data type. It will be automatically taken as 
              //Object variable if not specified. This is in a lot of modern programming languages.
    String str = {'H', 'i', '!'}; //Ability to create string from char array like in c++.
    char[] chs = "Hello!";  //Ability to create char array from string.
    
    boolean flag = 5; //boolean from number like in c++.
}
```

Something mentioned in 5. already is in java but its little bit unpractical and long code to do. In Java, String from char array is `new String(new char[] {'H', 'i', '!'})`. Char array from string is `"Hello".toCharArray()`. And boolean from number can be `flag = [some number] > 0 ? true : false`.

My changes will make my Java fresher and easier to learn.
I hope some of the things that I have mentioned will be possible to do. The question is how...

Comment: Nice suggestions! Although with the last one-- I remember I heard that they had a lot of discussions about Type inference (well, now we have var but it is not the same :) ). And did you mean that .toCharArray() is too much?

Comment: Excepted for (2), those are made-up "issues" solved by any IDE with auto-import feature and class templates

Comment: One thing that you'll have to figure out is what to call it. I'm sure that Java is already taken.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering about if it is possible to create the same programing language as Java is. Language with same libraries as in Java and other stuff but with modified syntax?

Yes it is possible.

For example, "just" write a new compiler<sup>1</sup> that takes source code in your new language, parses it, analyses it, and emits (valid) JVM bytecodes.

> Probably what I want to modify JVM and compilation process somehow.

You don't need to modify the JVM.  (Don't make the problem bigger than it needs to be.)

> I thought about a lot of improvements that I would like to implement in Java.

Thanks ... but that's not relevant to your question.  Provided that your new language has an unambiguous grammar, a sound type system and sensible semantics, what you want to do is possible.

---

<sup>1 - ... or, find and modify an existing compiler.  I am not advising a specific implementation approach.</sup>

Comment: thank you for your answer. So it is possible. But.... you said that it will be easier to create the whole compilator from scratch than just modifying an existing one?! If actually is then how? I do not want any python stuff because it supposed to be java and imagine how will it sounds: "You want better java? Ok! Step 1, download python...". Seriously there must be some better option, for example, Isn't JVM open-source or maybe some JavaCC stuff?

Comment: Yes, those are all options. I didn't mention "easier" (or python) in the answer at all.   I am trying to avoid giving you advice on the best way to do this because: 1) it will depend on the scope of the work, 2) it will depend on what you intend to do with the compiler, 3) it will depend on your skills ... and ability to resist the "scope creep" tendency.

Comment: If you want some real advice, I would advise that you do a lot of background reading on compilers and how to implement them. There are text books! Then find, and start looking at the source code of some existing Java compilers.  Do this >>before<< you start planning a way.  There are many ways to approach this problem, and none is clearly the "best" way.  (And don't imagine that this is a simple thing you can "knock off" in a couple of weeks by hacking on something.)

Answer (score 0):

Sample code below tries to highlight the points in the answer

- Note there is no package
- Class is named poorly, Highlights use of the different types of **class**es( interface, enum)
  -Use of multiple `Color`s without import.

Note there is no package, Class is named poorly.

1. Package is `optional` as long as your java class is in the root java directory.
2. Yes this is a quirk,
3. This is a feature **not a bug**. You do not need to automatically import things, This introduces bloat.
4. `public` is optional, You can do without it in which case the default value is `package private`.

   `class` is needed, or that place holder is needed and can be replaced with `enum`,
   `interface`, `@interface`
5. Language feature, Remember java is strongly typed. `String`.toCharArray() solves this imagined problem.

```java
interface a {
    
}

enum dda {
    LOW ,
    HIGH,
    DDA
}
class b{
    static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLUE + " is nice!");
        System.out.println(java.awt.Color.BLUE + " is also good!");
    }    
}
```

Comment: "You can do without it in which case the default value is public." > No, it would be package private.